# Is there a way to add RCTAnimation Module to my React native project

Tags: react-native

I recently started a new react native project in which I am trying to build a personal calendar. I am getting my calendar from (https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars) the simple calendar works fine once I fixed the 'hoist-non-react-statics but when I try the Agenda component, it doesn't render and throws the following error. (Animated: `useNativeDriver` is not supported because the native animated module is missing. Falling back to JS-based animation. To resolve this, add `RCTAnimation` module to this app).

I have tried multiple ways to fix it but somehow cant seem to and most of the posts are from 2016 and a older version of RN.

I am using windows 10, android studio and its an expo project.
following is the simple code i have so far.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {Calendar, CalendarList, Agenda} from 'react-native-calendars';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Taimoor</Text>
      <Agenda />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: already tried adding jest.mock('NativeAnimatedHelper') to jest setup file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the required module using this command:

```
npm i react-native-animation-library
```